# What is the best approach to work with DTO's and MVVM pattern (caliburn micro)?

Tags: .net, mvvm, architecture, caliburn.micro, dto

I am working on a project based on multitier architecture, that is, the persistence tier (database system), the server tier (to communicate with database, perform time-consuming tasks etc) and client tier (presentation, CRUD, etc).

The architecture is (almost) pretty common and simple. I use MVVM (Caliburn micro) for presentation and DTO's to transfer data between server application and client applications.

I think that a common approach for MVVM pattern here is to transfer (or somehow absorb) the DTO object to a ViewModel object (which is responsible for the way data is presented), as we want to separate transport objects from presentation objects (to avoid adding presentation behaviour to transport objects).

I believe this approach is correct, however I have some thoughts about it:

- i might want to re-use the way the object is presented from time to time
- i have a little feeling that this approach is not completely OK with single responsibility principle - the viewmodel in caliburn micro handles behaviour of the view (like reacting to user actions, etc.), so adding data holding/operating responsibility to it does not look good in my opinion
- i also think that having those two in separate classes improves project structure and code readability

Thus, I created another set of classes (called them ViewHelpers), which are holding data, the way it is presented (annotations like DisplayName, etc) and import/export from DTO behaviour. I connected them with interface, as they have pretty much the same behaviour (import, export, etc) and I wanted to generalize some of the ViewModels using generic inheritance (like EditViewModel, etc) to keep the structure of similar ViewModels consistent

I should also note that i am using Model classes to communicate with server service (methods for getting and saving dto objects).

Is this a good approach to this kind of problem? Am I missing something? Did I misunderstand the MVVM pattern, calling MVVM's Model as ViewHelper, and giving my Models wrong behaviour?

Thank you for anny suggestions. As my approach might not be completely clear by just describing it, let me present a short pseudocode example.

```
public interface IViewHelperOperations<T> //T is DTO object
{
    T Export();
    void Import(T item); 
}

public interface IModelOperations<T> //T is DTO object again
{
    T GetDTO();
    void SaveDTO(T item);
    //connecting with server service to save or get objects from database
}

public abstract class AGenericEditModel<T> //T is DTO again
{
    //data is binded to viewhelper object
    protected IModelOperations<T> model;
    protected IViewHelperOperations<T> viewHelper;

    public virtual SaveItem()
    {
        model.SaveDTO(viewHelper.Export());
    }
}

//i think that implementation of those is pretty obvious
```

Answer (score 0):

MVVM should be named MVMV (Model ViewModel View). 
But i think the reason is that MVVM just looks better.

One approach is:

- send your DTO to the Model or, if you want,the  DTO is your Model. Here your DTO can be deeply nested, what ever you want. Your Model does not have any behavior.
- flatten the Model in your ViewModel. Behavior resides here. But you are using the data in your Model.
- that allows your View to easily present your ViewModel.